# Heroku postgres error tryng to make a dataclip

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku

I was tryng to extract some data throught heroku postgres dataclips, I want to extract the data from multiple tables:

```
SELECT participants_team.short_name,results_teamscore.points,results_teamscore.score,draw_debateteam.side
FROM results_teamscore JOIN participants_team JOIN draw_debateteam
ON participants_team.id=draw_debateteam.id
```

But everytime that I add one condition with the sentence `AND` it stop working:

```
SELECT participants_team.short_name,results_teamscore.points,results_teamscore.score,draw_debateteam.side
FROM results_teamscore JOIN participants_team JOIN draw_debateteam
ON participants_team.id=draw_debateteam.id AND participants_team.id=results_teamscore.team_id
```

and give this message:

```
Dataclip Error
ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
LINE 5: 
        ^
```

I don´t know what could it be :c